# Python Beautiful soup get correct column headers for each table

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The following code gets player data but each dataset is different. The first data it sees is the quarterback data, so it uses these columns for all the data going forward. How can I change the header so that for every different dataset it encounters, the correct headers are used with the correct data?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/boxscore/_/gameId/401326313'# Create object page
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

rows = soup.select("table.mod-data tr")
#rows = soup.find_all("table.mod-data tr")
headers = [header.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for header in rows[0].find_all("th")]

data = [dict(zip(headers, [cell.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for cell in row.find_all("td")]))
        for row in rows[1:]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('_Data_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")),index=False)

# see what the data looks like at this point
pprint(data)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question completely, what is wrong with the quarterback data? Is it that only the quarterback data is shown but we want data from other players? What does correct header with correct data mean?

Comment: Are you saying that the tables all have different column names and it uses the first one when collecting all the player data? So you what you want is distinct tables each with the appropriate columns, not one big table with the columns of the first table?

Comment: have you considered using the api? `https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary?event=401326313`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned expected result is not that clear, but if you just wanna read the tables use `pandas.read_html` to achieve your goal - `index_col=0` avoids that the first column, that has no header is named *Unnamed_0*.

```
pd.read_html('https://www.espn.com/nfl/boxscore/_/gameId/401326313',index_col=0)
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd

for table in pd.read_html('https://www.espn.com/nfl/boxscore/_/gameId/401326313',index_col=0):
    pd.DataFrame(table).to_csv('_Data_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S.%f")))
```

As alternative you can `reset_index()` and use `to_csv(index=False)`:

```
pd.DataFrame(table).rename_axis('').reset_index().to_csv('_Data_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S.%f")),index=False)
```

### EDIT

Using captions in tables and to store results in named csv files:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/boxscore/_/gameId/401326313'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


for table in soup.select('article.boxscore-tabs table'):
    caption = '_'.join(table.parent.select_one('.table-caption').text.split(' '))
    df = pd.read_html(table.prettify(),index_col=0)[0].rename_axis('').reset_index()
    df.insert(0, 'caption', caption)
    df.to_csv(f'_DATA_{caption}_{pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")}.csv',index=False)
```

#### Output of your csv files

```html
caption,,C/ATT,YDS,AVG,TD,INT,SACKS,QBR,RTG
Miami_Passing,Tua Tagovailoa  T. Tagovailoa,16/27,202,7.5,1,1,2-17,47.5,79.6
Miami_Passing,TEAM,16/27,185,7.5,1,1,2-17,--,79.6

caption,,C/ATT,YDS,AVG,TD,INT,SACKS,QBR,RTG
New_England_Passing,Mac Jones  M. Jones,29/39,281,7.2,1,0,1-13,76.9,102.6
New_England_Passing,TEAM,29/39,268,7.2,1,0,1-13,--,102.6

caption,,CAR,YDS,AVG,TD,LONG
Miami_Rushing,Myles Gaskin  M. Gaskin,9,49,5.4,0,15
Miami_Rushing,Malcolm Brown  M. Brown,5,16,3.2,0,5
Miami_Rushing,Jacoby Brissett  J. Brissett,2,4,2.0,0,2
Miami_Rushing,Salvon Ahmed  S. Ahmed,3,4,1.3,0,8
Miami_Rushing,Tua Tagovailoa  T. Tagovailoa,4,1,0.3,1,3
Miami_Rushing,TEAM,23,74,3.2,1,15

caption,,CAR,YDS,AVG,TD,LONG
New_England_Rushing,Damien Harris  D. Harris,23,100,4.3,0,35
New_England_Rushing,James White  J. White,4,12,3.0,0,10
New_England_Rushing,Jonnu Smith  J. Smith,1,6,6.0,0,6
New_England_Rushing,Brandon Bolden  B. Bolden,1,5,5.0,0,5
New_England_Rushing,Rhamondre Stevenson  R. Stevenson,1,2,2.0,0,2
New_England_Rushing,TEAM,30,125,4.2,0,35

caption,,REC,YDS,AVG,TD,LONG,TGTS
Miami_Receiving,DeVante Parker  D. Parker,4,81,20.3,0,30,7
Miami_Receiving,Jaylen Waddle  J. Waddle,4,61,15.3,1,36,5
Miami_Receiving,Myles Gaskin  M. Gaskin,5,27,5.4,0,12,5
Miami_Receiving,Salvon Ahmed  S. Ahmed,2,24,12.0,0,18,3
Miami_Receiving,Durham Smythe  D. Smythe,1,9,9.0,0,9,2
Miami_Receiving,Albert Wilson  A. Wilson,0,0,0.0,0,0,2
Miami_Receiving,Mike Gesicki  M. Gesicki,0,0,0.0,0,0,3
Miami_Receiving,TEAM,16,202,12.6,1,36,27

caption,,REC,YDS,AVG,TD,LONG,TGTS
New_England_Receiving,Nelson Agholor  N. Agholor,5,72,14.4,1,25,7
New_England_Receiving,James White  J. White,6,49,8.2,0,26,7
New_England_Receiving,Jakobi Meyers  J. Meyers,6,44,7.3,0,22,9
New_England_Receiving,Jonnu Smith  J. Smith,5,42,8.4,0,11,5
New_England_Receiving,Hunter Henry  H. Henry,3,31,10.3,0,16,3
New_England_Receiving,Kendrick Bourne  K. Bourne,1,17,17.0,0,17,3
New_England_Receiving,Damien Harris  D. Harris,2,17,8.5,0,9,3
New_England_Receiving,Rhamondre Stevenson  R. Stevenson,1,9,9.0,0,9,1
New_England_Receiving,TEAM,29,281,9.7,1,26,38

caption,,FUM,LOST,REC
Miami_Fumbles,Xavien Howard  X. Howard,0,0,1
Miami_Fumbles,Zach Sieler  Z. Sieler,0,0,1
Miami_Fumbles,TEAM,0,0,2

caption,,FUM,LOST,REC
New_England_Fumbles,David Andrews  D. Andrews,0,0,1
New_England_Fumbles,Damien Harris  D. Harris,1,1,0
New_England_Fumbles,Rhamondre Stevenson  R. Stevenson,1,1,0
New_England_Fumbles,Jonnu Smith  J. Smith,1,0,1
New_England_Fumbles,Mac Jones  M. Jones,1,0,0
New_England_Fumbles,TEAM,4,2,2

caption,,tackles,tackles,tackles,tackles,misc,misc,misc,misc
,,TOT,SOLO,SACKS,TFL,PD,QB HTS,TD,Unnamed: 8_level_1
Miami_Defensive,Jerome Baker  J. Baker,12,9,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Eric Rowe  E. Rowe,9,6,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Byron Jones  B. Jones,6,5,0,0,1,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Nik Needham  N. Needham,6,5,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Sam Eguavoen  S. Eguavoen,6,2,0,0,0,3,0,
Miami_Defensive,Xavien Howard  X. Howard,5,4,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Jason McCourty  J. McCourty,5,3,0,0,1,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Brennan Scarlett  B. Scarlett,5,2,0,0,1,1,0,
Miami_Defensive,Andrew Van Ginkel  A. Van Ginkel,5,2,0,0,0,1,0,
Miami_Defensive,John Jenkins  J. Jenkins,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Emmanuel Ogbah  E. Ogbah,3,3,0,1,1,1,0,
Miami_Defensive,Zach Sieler  Z. Sieler,3,2,0,1,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Christian Wilkins  C. Wilkins,3,2,0,0,0,1,0,
Miami_Defensive,Elandon Roberts  E. Roberts,2,2,0,0,1,1,0,
Miami_Defensive,Jamal Perry  J. Perry,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Brandon Jones  B. Jones,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Jevon Holland  J. Holland,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Adam Butler  A. Butler,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Mack Hollins  M. Hollins,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Team  Team,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Mike Gesicki  M. Gesicki,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Durham Smythe  D. Smythe,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Miami_Defensive,Jaelan Phillips  J. Phillips,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
Miami_Defensive,TEAM,87,60,1,2,5,9,0,

caption,,tackles,tackles,tackles,tackles,misc,misc,misc,misc
,,TOT,SOLO,SACKS,TFL,PD,QB HTS,TD,Unnamed: 8_level_1
New_England_Defensive,Kyle Dugger  K. Dugger,7,6,0,1,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Devin McCourty  D. McCourty,7,4,0,0,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Ja'Whaun Bentley  J. Bentley,4,4,0,1,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Matthew Judon  M. Judon,4,3,0,1,0,1,0,
New_England_Defensive,Lawrence Guy  L. Guy,4,2,0,0,0,1,0,
New_England_Defensive,Dont'a Hightower  D. Hightower,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,J.C. Jackson  J.C. Jackson,3,3,0,0,1,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Kyle Van Noy  K. Van Noy,3,2,1,1,1,1,0,
New_England_Defensive,Adrian Phillips  A. Phillips,3,2,0,2,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Davon Godchaux  D. Godchaux,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Jalen Mills  J. Mills,2,2,0,0,1,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Josh Uche  J. Uche,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,
New_England_Defensive,Carl Davis  C. Davis,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Chase Winovich  C. Winovich,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Joejuan Williams  J. Williams,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Christian Barmore  C. Barmore,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,Jonathan Jones  J. Jones,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
New_England_Defensive,TEAM,49,36,2,7,4,4,0,

caption,,INT,YDS,TD
Miami_Interceptions,No Miami Interceptions,,,

caption,,INT,YDS,TD
New_England_Interceptions,Jonathan Jones  J. Jones,1,0,0
New_England_Interceptions,TEAM,1,0,0

caption,,NO,YDS,AVG,LONG,TD
Miami_Kick_Returns,No Miami Kick Returns,,,,,

caption,,NO,YDS,AVG,LONG,TD
New_England_Kick_Returns,Brandon Bolden  B. Bolden,1,23,23.0,23,0
New_England_Kick_Returns,Gunner Olszewski  G. Olszewski,1,17,17.0,17,0
New_England_Kick_Returns,TEAM,2,40,20.0,23,0

caption,,NO,YDS,AVG,LONG,TD
Miami_Punt_Returns,Jakeem Grant Sr.  J. Grant Sr.,1,18,18.0,18,0
Miami_Punt_Returns,TEAM,1,18,18.0,18,0

caption,,NO,YDS,AVG,LONG,TD
New_England_Punt_Returns,Gunner Olszewski  G. Olszewski,3,20,6.7,14,0
New_England_Punt_Returns,TEAM,3,20,6.7,14,0

caption,,FG,PCT,LONG,XP,PTS
Miami_Kicking,Jason Sanders  J. Sanders,1/1,100.0,48,2/2,5
Miami_Kicking,TEAM,1/1,100.0,48,2/2,5

caption,,FG,PCT,LONG,XP,PTS
New_England_Kicking,Nick Folk  N. Folk,3/3,100.0,42,1/1,10
New_England_Kicking,TEAM,3/3,100.0,42,1/1,10

caption,,NO,YDS,AVG,TB,In 20,LONG
Miami_Punting,Michael Palardy  M. Palardy,4,180,45.0,1,0,52
Miami_Punting,TEAM,4,180,45.0,1,0,52

caption,,NO,YDS,AVG,TB,In 20,LONG
New_England_Punting,Jake Bailey  J. Bailey,2,99,49.5,1,0,62
New_England_Punting,TEAM,2,99,49.5,1,0,62
```

Comment: amazingly short and effective solution. I added these 2 lines: data = pd.DataFrame(table)
    data.to_csv('_Data_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")),index=False). However I noticed that when the file was exported to csv the player name was missing. Result was data with out player.

Comment: @LeoTorres - Just in case you need to know what is stored in the csv - Added  an additional example that works also with the captions of the table to name the csv files.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt. A few things to note. I am not printing to CSV but just showing you the dataframes with the correct header information, you can handle the CSV output later.

You press enter after running the program to see the next tables with different headers.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


#Made this function because the rows we want for different headers are different.
def get_individual_table(headers, rows, start,end):
    '''for header in headers:
        print(header)'''


    data = [dict(zip(headers, [cell.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for cell in row.find_all("td")]))
            for row in rows[start+1:end]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    #print(df)
    return df

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/boxscore/_/gameId/401326313'# Create object page
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

rows = soup.select("table.mod-data tr")

row_team_names = soup.select("div.team-name")

#rows = soup.find_all("table.mod-data tr")


#Only some of the row indicies have correct header information, we find them here.
correct_row_indices = []
for idx, row in enumerate(rows):
    #print(idx, row.find_all("th"))
    if len(row.find_all("th"))>0:
        correct_row_indices.append(idx)


print(correct_row_indices)
headers = [header.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for header in rows[0].find_all("th")]

team_names =[]

for name in row_team_names:
    team_names.append(name.text)
    

for i in range(len(correct_row_indices)-1):
    headers = [header.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for header in rows[correct_row_indices[i]].find_all("th")]
    #print(headers)
    

    #Use the function to get the tables individually
    df = get_individual_table(headers, rows, correct_row_indices[i], correct_row_indices[i+1])
    if not df.empty:
        df["Team Name"] = team_names[i]

    #Press enter to see each individual table.
    print(df)
    input()
    df.to_csv('_Data_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")),index=False)
    
    






#df.to_csv('_Data_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")),index=False)

# see what the data looks like at this point
#pprint(data)
```

Here is part of the output:
[image]

As you can see, we get each distinct DataFrame with the different headers as necessary. Observe how each DataFrame matches the table on the ESPN site:

[image]

You can choose how to process them individually later in the loop logic.
Not all tables are shown. Please keep pressing enter after initially running the program and all the table information on that page will eventually display.

Edit:
I have changed the code to output individual CSV files for each table.
[image]

I show the first two tables outputted above.

Comment: @RicrardKYu the code you supplied displays data. I changed a few lines to output the data to a csv file but the csv files created are empty. Here are my code changes to your code                  data = get_individual_table(headers, rows, correct_row_indices[i], correct_row_indices[i+1])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('_Data_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")),index=False)

Comment: I see, do you need any help exporting to CSV, or is this alright so far.

Comment: Yes Richard i need data in a format where I can insert it into a database

Comment: I have updated the code to make a CSV file after every time we press enter. Is it alright if it is multiple CSV files?

Comment: Yes @Richard it has to be multiple files because the tables all have different schemas. Is there any way to add the table name "Miami Receiving" as a value for all rows in a column? I just realized that once I have hundreds of games I am not going to know who is on what team.

Comment: So to confirm you want a column that just says Miami Receiving or whatever the table heading happens?

Comment: @LeoTorres I have changed the code to reflect this. I have updated the picture to show the team names next to the players too. It should reflect in the CSV as well. There may be an IndexError at the end but all the tables will be accounted for.